# What's the difference between green and blue inns?

Tags: wizards-unite

When plotting my walks I'm noticing there are multiple types of inns. Some have blue roofs, and some have green.

There's no visual variation in other building types, so does this mean I can get different things from different inns?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The difference between the inns is related to which types of meals they serve. When you swipe the inn, you will be served a random meal from the options and given Spell Energy based on the meal that is selected. [Stated by Niantic](https://twitter.com/NianticHelp/status/1142251889444020224), these numbers have been changed since initial released

**Inns**

1. Brown Inns - Afternoon Tea, Fish & Chips
2. Purple Inn - Tomato Soup and Pumpkin Juice
3. Green Inns - Bertie Bott's Beans, Bangers & Mash, Honeyduke's Bar, and Turkey Dinner
4. Blue Inn - Pumpkin Juice, Fish & Chips, and Butter Beer
5. Pink Inns - Afternoon Tea

**Meals**

1. Afternoon Tea, Provides 3 Spell Energy
2. Tomato Soup, Provides 3 Spell Energy
3. Bertie Bott's Beans, Provides 3 Spell Energy
4. Pumpkin Juice, Provides 3 Spell Energy
5. Bangers & Mash, Provides 5 Spell Energy
6. Fish & Chips, Provides 6 Spell Energy
7. Honeyduke's Bar, Provides 6 Spell Energy
8. Honeyduke's Bar, Provides 7 Spell Energy
9. Turkey Dinner, Provides 10 Spell Energy

*Some sources say these are not in the game (yet)*

10. Egg on Toast, Provides 2 Spell Energy
11. Pumpkin Pastry, Provides 2 Spell Energy
12. Treacle Tart, Provides 3 Spell Energy
13. Violet Pudding, Provides 3 Spell Energy
14. Turkey Leg, Provides 3 Spell Energy

---

**Sources**

- [WizardsUnite Hub](https://wizardsunitehub.info/wiki/inns/)
- [WizardsUnite Gamepress](https://wizardsunite.gamepress.gg/guide/food-and-inns-spell-energy-gain-guide)
- [IMore](https://www.imore.com/harry-potter-wizards-unite-what-are-inns-and-how-do-they-work)

Comment: I would also use text to provide the information, in case the image and link go down.  In addition, these numbers are actually outdated now, as [Niantic ended up increasing Spell Energy yields](https://twitter.com/NianticHelp/status/1142251889444020224).  I know for a fact that both the Pumpkin Juice and the Beans give you 3 instead of 2.

Comment: @Jamal I took a screenshot of the chart personally and uploaded the image for StackExchange to host, so I doubt the image will go bad anytime soon. However, thanks for the update on the spell energy changes! I will update my answer shortly to reflect the new changes, and convert the image to text for easier updates in the future